# Got temporary error 899 'Rowid already allocated' from NDBCLUSTER

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

im experiencing this NDB CLUSTER Error for a while now.
It started after a cluster shutdown for 2 days due to production shutdown.

Any insights will help. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

899 means that the rowid is already allocated.
It is a problem due to the distributed nature of
NDB Cluster. Normally it is a temporary problem
that goes away after a few microseconds.

If it stays then probably some bug have caused the
primary replica and backup replica to be inconsistent.

If that is the scenario the best method to get
back to normal operation is to do the following:
1) Take a backup
2) Perform an initial node restart of one of the data nodes
(presuming that you have 2 data nodes).

The problem should hopefully go away after this.
The backup is simply to ensure that you have the
latest possible backup if something more happens.

Comment: I eventually found out what the problem is few days later after I've posted this. I have 4 Data Nodes, one of the nodes experiences a delay on the replication process as I observe the replication of pages on cluster start-up. I have shutdown the infected node and my processes starts to work fine again. Thanks btw